# Sonar wants to close the Stream

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

I have a next code:

```
private Stream<Field> getStreamWithAccessibleFields(final Object object) {
    return Arrays.stream(object.getClass()
            .getDeclaredFields()).peek(field -> field.setAccessible(true));
}
```

Sonar throws me an issue: **[MINOR] Close this "Stream". squid:S2095**.
Can anybody give an advice, how I can handle this problem?

Comment: So Sonar does a double fault. First, there are streams which might not require closing, second, closing a resource that is returned to the caller would be wrong for any kind of `AutoCloseable`…

Comment: Still, I’d prefer the bulk operation for efficiency: `Field[] fields=object.getClass() .getDeclaredFields(); AccessibleObject.setAccessible(fields, true); return Arrays.stream(fields);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a false positive that is already fixed and soon to be released with SonarQube Java 3.14.

For further reference, please check [SONARJAVA-1478](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1478).

Comment: Uh? Link is not dead.

Comment: Ahh.. My company's network was stopping me from accessing that link.  I do apologies for wasting your time.